# Deleting an object via std::weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-smart-ptr

I have a std::vector with thousands of objects, stored as shared_ptr. Since the object has many attributes that can be used for searching, I maintain multiple indexes to this std::vector on std::map and std::multimap using weak_ptr.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> Objects;
std::map<int,std::weak_ptr<Object>> IndexByEmployeeId;
std::multimap<std::string,std::weak_ptr<Object>> IndexByName;
```

Since the map and multimap are balanced binary trees, the search/modify are super fast. However, I am a bit foxed about delete. I want to delete after looking up the object via one of the indexes. Locking the weak_ptr gives me shared_ptr, but it doesn't allow me to destroy object on the vector. Is there any way to delete the original object on the vector?

Comment: Why do you even want to manually delete an object held by a `shared_ptr`? That defeats the purpose of using `shared_ptr`

Comment: How about removing the `shared_pr` from the vector? There is no magic here - removing the the `shared_ptr` from the vector will call its destructor (unless you remove by moving). If there aren't any other `shared_ptr` instances holding up the ref-count to the referenced object, the destructor of the `shared_ptr` will automatically release the memory of the instance of  `Object`. Remember to properly check the success of `std::weak_ptr::lock()` afterwards, i.e. check the result against `nullptr`, or simultaneously remove the `weak_ptr`s in your maps.

Comment: Removing from the vector means I have to iterate over the vector to find and remove it. That defeats the purpose of having indexes. Please note I am not trying to understand the working of smart_ptr/weak_ptr.. Is there any way to reset() the smart_ptr on the vector, without iterating over it? I only have a weak_ptr to the object.

Comment: So do you have the index of the `shared_ptr` in `Objects`? If yes then what is the problem with calling `.reset()` on it? Otherwise no, you can't hack the `shared_ptr` through a `weak_ptr`, you need to access the actual one (which means finding it in the vector)

Comment: I don't have the "i" to call Objects[i].reset() function.

Comment: Besides, any numeric index I store will get invalidated when items are removed from the vector.

Comment: You can't escape the fact that you need to know the location in the vector to erase it from the vector. I think you will have to reevaluate your whole structure. Could you make the `std::map` the owner/primary-index and use `std::unique_ptr` then other indexes could simply use raw pointers that can be found and removed quickly?

Comment: If you store the objects by `shared_ptr`, then they are **obviously** not owned by `Objects` and hence must not be deleted (but at most removed from `Objects`).

Comment: @Walter: Uhm, what? Everyone holding a `shared_ptr` has shared ownership of the `Object` instance - that's the whole point. The only "consensus" is: the last remaining owner is responsible for destruction (unless released prior to the last referencing `shared_ptr` dtor). The vector `Objects` is definitely an owner - the maps are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems from what you've posted that your data structures are inappropriate for what you want to do.

1. `shared_ptr` should only be used to express shared ownership. However, your posted code and your desire to delete the objects pointed to indicate that `Objects` is in fact the sole owner of its objects.
2. Your `vector<shared_ptr<object>>` appears to be used only as data storage container (the desired functionality of searching by id or name is implemented elsewhere), but removing elements from a `vector` is typically expensive, so you may better use another type of container.

If there are no other `shared_ptr` to your objects, then your design is poor. In this case you shouldn't use any smart pointers but simply `container<object>` and maps into the that. For example something like this (not tested not even compiled):

```
struct data_t { std::string name; /* more data */ };
using objt_map = std::map<std::size_t,data_t>;
using object   = objt_map::value_type;    // pair<const size_t,data_t>
using obj_it   = objt_map::iterator;
using name_map = std::multimap<std::string, obj_it>;
objt_map Objects;
name_map NameMap;

std::forward_list<obj_it> find_by_name(std::string const&name) const
{
    auto range = NameMap.equal_range(name);
    std::forward_list<obj_it> result;
    for(auto it=range.first; it!=range.second; ++it)
        result.push_front(it->second);
    return result;
}

std::forward_list<obj_it> find_by_id(std::size_t id) const
{
    auto it = Objects.find(name);
    return {it == Objects.end()? 0:1, it};
}

void insert_object(std::size_t id, data_t const&data)
{
    auto it = Objects.find(id);
    if(it != Objects.end())
        throw std::runtime_error("id '"+std::to_string(id)+"' already known");
    Objects[id] = data;
    NameMap.emplace(data.name, Objects.find(id));
}

void delete_object(obj_it it)
{
    if(it==Objects.end())
        throw std::runtime_error("attempt to delete invalid object");
    auto range = NameMap.equal_range(it->second.name);
    for(auto i=range.first; i!=range.second; ++i)
        if(i->second==it) {
            NameMap.erase(i);
            break;
        }
    Objects.erase(it);
}
```

Note iterators of `std::map` remain valid upon insertion and deletion (of other objects), such that the returns from the finders are not invalidated by insertion and deletion. I use `std::forward_list<obj_it>` to return objects to allow for returning none or several.

Comment: The object is created elsewhere and comes to me as shared_ptr. Once the object is stored, it does own it. The object itself has members, some are again smart_ptr. The smart_ptr was used because it is very easy to transfer the objects across functions while avoiding copying every time. I can check the feasibility of using unique_ptr and move() instead of smart_ptr.

Comment: @Sharath It sounds like it probably should not be created as a `shared_ptr` if your part of the system owns it. Do you have any control over that? Usually when objects are created they are placed in a `unique_ptr` because that gives the consumer the choice to move it into a `shared_ptr` only if they need that.

Comment: I do have control over the whole system. But the object gets created in a different module and gets passed over a few functions, before it gets stored. I want to avoid copies since these are complex objects.

Comment: @Walter, I am a bit concerned about how you are storing objt_map::iterator in the multimap. Won't the iterator get invalidated as more entries are inserted into the object map?

Comment: @Sharath As I pointed out, the existing iterators of a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) remain valid upon insertion and deletion (apart from iterators to the deleted objects, of course).

Comment: Obtaining the objects via `smart_ptr` and then owning it makes no sense. If you own it, you should not import it via a `shared_ptr`, but by moving a `unique_ptr`. This is the natural C++ way to transfer ownership. A `shared_ptr` expresses shared ownership, thus the resource from which you obtain it may/does retain some share of the ownership and you must not delete the object (which defies the whole point of smart pointers: they should delete the object automatically).

Comment: Ah, I missed that comment.

Comment: @Sharath Do you have C++14?

Comment: Alright, I think I will change it to unique_ptr and use the move function. And switch from vector to map. My code needs to compile under Debian (gcc 4.9.2) and Win64 (VC++ 2015). Not sure C++14 is fully supported.

Answer (score 2):

This can be a use case where `std::set` is the appropriate choice over `std::vector`. `std::set` guarantees lookup, insertion and removal in logarithmic time. So you can lookup an object by index in one of your maps objects and then delete it in any container with `log(N)` performance.

I would suggest this approach if insertion/removal operations represent the performance bottleneck in your application.

By the way, consider carefully the actual need for `shared_ptr`, because `shared_ptr` comes with a certain performance overhead as opposed to `unique_ptr` for example. Your owner container could use `unique_ptr` and the various maps could simply use raw pointers.

Comment: Lookup of an object in a set by "index"? Really?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition No, lookup in one of the other maps.

Comment: By the way, stick with the `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` safety until you have an actual need not to.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I would suggest the opposite. Don't use `std::shared_ptr` unless you absolutely need shared ownership. `std::unique_ptr` is faster, smaller and should be the first choice.

Comment: Thanks. Let me look at the performance penalty for moving from vector to set in my application. Need to do some bench marking.

Comment: @Galik: Well, I agree that `unique_ptr` is a better choice if you don't need sharedness, but the OP _does_ need sharedness and raw pointers should be your last resort.

Answer (score 1):

So, here is another option, based on importing the objects by moving `std::unique_ptr<>`. Unfortunately, `unique_ptr`s are not useful keys for `std::set` (since they are unique), unless you have C++14, when `set::find()` can take another argument than a key (see below).

For a **C++11** approach, one must therefore use `std::map` to store the `unique_ptr`s, which requires doubling the `id` and `name` entries: once in `data_t` and once as keys in the `map`s. Here is a sketch.

```
struct data_t {
    const std::size_t id;       // changing these would
    const std::string name;     // lead to confusion
    /* more data */
};
using data_ptr = std::unique_ptr<data_t>;
using data_map = std::map<std::size_t,data_ptr>;
using obj_it   = data_map::iterator;
using name_map = std::multimap<std::string,obj_it>;
data_map DataSet;
name_map NameMap;

std::vector<data_t*> find_by_name(std::string const&name) const
{
    auto range = NameMap.equal_range(name);
    std::vector<data_t*> result;
    result.reserve(std::distance(range.first,range.second));
    for(auto it=range.first; it!=range.second; ++it)
        result.push_back(it->second->get());
    return result;
}

data_t* find_by_id(std::size_t id) const
{
    auto it = DataSet.find(id);
    return it == DataSet.end()? nullptr : it->second.get();
}

// transfer ownership here
void insert_object(data_ptr&&ptr)
{
    const auto id = ptr->id;
    if(DataSet.count(id))
        throw std::runtime_error("id '"+std::to_string(id)+"' already known");
    auto itb = DataSet.emplace(id,std::move(ptr));
    auto err = itb.second;
    if(!err)
        err = NameMap.emplace(itb.first->name,itb.first).second;
    if(err)
        throw std::runtime_error("couldn't insert id  "+std::to_string(id));
}

// remove object given an observing pointer; invalidates ptr
void delete_object(data_t*ptr)
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return;                 // issue warning or throw ?
    auto it = DataSet.find(ptr->id);
    if(it==DataSet.end())
        throw std::runtime_error("attempt to delete an unknown object");
    auto range = NameMap.equal_range(it->second->name);
    for(auto i=range.first; i!=range.second; ++i)
        if(i->second==it) {
            NameMap.erase(i);
            break;
        }
    DataSet.erase(it);
}
```

Here is a sketch for a **C++14** solution, which avoids the duplication of the `id` and `name` data in the maps, but requires/assumes that `data_t::id` and `data_t::name` are invariable.

```
struct data_t {
    const std::size_t id;       // used as key in set & multiset:
    const std::string name;     // must never be changed
    /* more data */
};

using data_ptr = std::unique_ptr<data_t>;

struct compare_id {
    using is_transparent = std::size_t;
    static bool operator(data_ptr const&l, data_ptr const&r)
    { return l->id < r->id; }
    static bool operator(data_ptr const&l, std::size_t r)
    { return l->id < r; }
    static bool operator(std::size_t l, data_ptr const&r)
    { return l < r->id; }
};

using data_set = std::set<data_ptr,compare_id>;
using data_it  = data_set::const_iterator;

struct compare_name {
    using is_transparent = std::string;
    static bool operator(data_it l, data_it r)
    { return (*l)->name < (*r)->name; }
    static bool operator(data_it l, std::string const&r)
    { return (*l)->name < r; }
    static bool operator(std::string const&l, data_it r)
    { return l < (*r)->name; }
};

using name_set = std::multiset<data_it,compare_name>;

data_set DataSet;
name_set NameSet;

std::vector<data_t*> find_by_name(std::string const&name) const
{
    auto range = NameSet.equal_range(name);
    std::vector<data_t*> result;
    result.reserve(std::distance(range.first,range.second));
    for(auto it=range.first; it!=range.second; ++it)
        result.push_back((*it)->get());
    return result;
}

data_t* find_by_id(std::size_t id) const
{
    auto it = DataSet.find(id);
    return it == DataSet.end()? nullptr : it->get();
}

// transfer ownership here
void insert_object(data_ptr&&ptr)
{
    const auto id = ptr->id;
    if(DataSet.count(id))
        throw std::runtime_error("id '"+std::to_string(id)+"' already known");
    auto itb = DataSet.emplace(std::move(ptr));
    auto err = itb.second;
    if(!err)
        err = NameSet.emplace(itb.first).second;
    if(err)
        throw std::runtime_error("couldn't insert id  "+std::to_string(id));
}

// remove object given an observing pointer; invalidates ptr
void delete_object(data_t*ptr)
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return;                 // issue warning or throw ?
    auto it = DataSet.find(ptr->id);
    if(it==DataSet.end())
        throw std::runtime_error("attempt to delete an unknown object");
    auto range = NameSet.equal_range(ptr->name);
    for(auto i=range.first; i!=range.second; ++i)
        if((*i)==it) {
            NameSet.erase(i);
            break;
        }
    DataSet.erase(it);
}
```

There may well be some bugs in here, in particular errors with dereferencing the various iterator and pointer types (though once it compiles these should be okay).